# Proof of integrability of a function when mesh(P)<delta

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The following is a question that I got in class. Apparently it's an easy proof, and I have written one out, just need it checked.
*Question:*

Let $f$ : $[a,b]$ $\to \mathbb{R}$  and let $I \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that for every $\varepsilon \gt 0$, there exists some $\delta \gt 0$ such that:
$$\vert I - R(f;P,\xi)\vert \lt \varepsilon$$ 
for every partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ with mesh($P$) < $\delta$ and every choice of tag $\boldsymbol \xi $ of *P*. Prove that $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$ and:
$$\int_a^bf(x) dx = I $$

*Proof:*

Let $\varepsilon \gt 0 $ arbitrarily. Let $P_1$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ which has mesh$(P_1) \lt \delta$. Now add a point to $P_1$ and we get the partition $P_2$ of $[a,b]$. Now, mesh$(P_2) \le $ mesh$(P_1) \lt \delta$. We can then add a point to the partition $P_2$ and we get $P_3$, a partition of $[a,b]$. Again, we have that mesh$(P_3) \le $ mesh$(P_2) \le $ mesh $(P_1) \le \delta$. Continuing this process indefinitely, we can form a sequence of partitions $(P_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ where mesh$(P_k) \le \delta$ for all $k$ and $\lim_{k \to \infty}$  mesh$(P_k)=0$. Now, we can write $\vert I - R(f;P,\xi)\vert \lt \varepsilon$ for all $k$ and so, taking limits:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\vert I - R(f;P,\xi)\vert \lt \varepsilon$$
$$\vert I - \lim_{k \to \infty}R(f;P,\xi)\vert \lt \varepsilon$$
by continuity of the Euclidean norm. So this (and the fact that $\varepsilon \gt 0$) implies that $\lim_{k \to \infty}R(f;P,\xi) = I$, as required.

Comment: what is your definition of Riemann integrability. Some textbook authors treat the conditions of your question as a definition of Riemann integrability. So perhaps your book has a different definition.

Comment: The definition that my book uses is:
A function f is said to be integrable (over [a,b]) if there exists a real number I with the property that, for every sequence (Pk) of partitions of [a,b], with the limit as k --> infinity of the mesh(Pk)=0 and every choice of tag (xi)k of Pk for each natural number k, the limit as k--> infinity of R(f;Pk,(xi)k)=I.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh

Comment: I think you need to modify your proof a bit. The sequence $P_{k}$ should be arbitrary with only one requirement that mesh of $P_{k}$ tends to $0$ as $k \to \infty$. Your proof is specifically creating one sequence $P_{k}$ of partitions. You see that your definition requires it to holds for every such sequence of partitions and not just for one sequence.

Comment: I will add an answer here with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_{k}$ be any sequence of partitions of $[a, b]$ such that $\mu(P_{k}) \to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. I have used $\mu(P)$ to denote mesh of partition $P$. Also let $\xi_{k}$ denote any choice of tagging for partitions $P_{k}$.

We are given that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $$|I - R(f;P,\xi)| < \epsilon$$ for all partitions $P$ and tagging $\xi$ of $P$ with $\mu(P) < \delta$.

We have to use the above condition to establish the following:

*For any given $\epsilon > 0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $$|I - R(f;P_{k}, \xi_{k})| < \epsilon$$ for all $k \geq N$.*

Now this is easy to do. For the given $\epsilon > 0$ we choose $\delta > 0$ (this is possible because of the given condition). Now $\mu(P_{k}) \to 0$ and hence there is a positive integer $N$ such that $\mu(P_{k}) < \delta$ whenever $k \geq N$. And then by given condition we have $$|I - R(f;P_{k},\xi_{k})| < \epsilon$$ whenever $k \geq N$. Thus we get the conclusion as desired and $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$ with integral $I$.

Comment: Thanks for that. I prefer your proof, and did consider doing it this way too. Will just check it with my prof to see if he's happy with the rigour. Thanks again!

Comment: I checked my proof. There is another mistake in my proof, beyond the fact that it's only for a paticular sequence. The finer partitions method doesn't necessarily mean that the limit to infinity of the mesh of the partitions goes to zero. One could infinitely add points to the non-mesh subintervals of the partition and so the mesh will stay the same size and not go to zero. Thanks again for your proof.

Comment: @KennethMano: good observation! Yes that was another problem. There is a further issue and that is your approach does not even guarantee that limit of $R(f:P_k, \xi_k) $ exists. It can only say that if the limit exists then it would have to be $I$.

Comment: You may upvote the answer when you get enough reputation on this site.

Comment: Will do. Thanks so much.